# Select numerical value with +/- buttons or manually entering?

Tags: gui-design, interaction-design, buttons, input, controls

The design I'm working on has the user assigning a value to each item, then if the value is more than 1, a second dependent attribute appears (as shown). I want the numbers to be large and not default to an ugly and busy text box. However, the only solution I could think of is an even uglier and busier -/+ button combo which is also incredibly space expensive (and, I've found, nearly impossible to fit in mobile mode).

Is there a better way to do this?

[image]

Comment: As it stands there isn't enough information in this question to be able to answer it. How likely is it that users will want any attribute to be significantly different from its starting value? Is this information something the user is very used to entering like a birth date or credit card number? How important are updates to the visual style of the numbers to the numbers themselves (e.g. if changing one number would dramatically affect other numbers, waiting for a field to lose focus is probably going to cause issues)?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? Maybe you could just write an answer yourself or accept whichever helped you solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

What about the following UI controls: textfields (restricted to numbers) to access any number a user need.

[image]

Comment: I find that standard UI control to be one of the worst ever invented. The tiny + and - buttons are very hard to acquire, making operation on them very slow. On touch, they are plain impossible to use.

Comment: A good innovation (which I first noticed in photoshop) is the ability to increment and decrement using the up and down cursor keys and the scroll wheel. Then, the +/- buttons are just there as a hint to make that shortcut a little more discoverable. In the same way nobody clicks the arrow buttons on the scrollbar anymore.

Comment: @André It's true that this design is less usable on smaller textfield. Combining it Peter's answer below would address this.

Answer (score 1):

Plus/minus buttons as a UI for picking a value can be an acceptable solution, but only in specific cases, such as:

- The range of possible choices is small (so the user isn't left clicking 20 times)
- There is an immediate visible effect when changing the value (e.g. updating a graph)

If the number of choices is relatively small, you could just use a drop-down select box. This would allow you to style the number quite large, and to change it you simply click/tap the number to open the select box.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following approach: normally the numbers appear as-is, without any additional buttons or textboxes. However when the user touches the number, a small slider appears underneath, with labels "+" and "−" at the ends. Sliding the number to the right would increase its value (the speed of increase depends on the distance from the center of the slider), and sliding to the left reduces it. When the user releases her touch, the number moves back to the original position, lined up with the rest of the numbers.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fULh7Z.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

If horizontal space is really at a premium, you can make the slider vertical instead, in which case when adjusting a number you would dim down all other numbers and paint the controls on top some of them.